# Чем заменить Executor при переходе на aiogram 3?

Tags: python, asyncio, aiogram-3.x

Есть бот, написанный с использованием Executor aiogram 2.25. Совместно крутится поллинг и таск для работы с БД. При выходе по Ctrl/C поллинг и таск штатно закрываются. Структурно код такой:

```
from aiogram.utils import executor

async def on_start(_):
    asyncio.create_task(periodic())
    db_pool = await asyncpg.create_pool(DATABASE_URL)

async def on_stop(_):
    await bot.close()
    await db_pool.close()    

@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def start_command(message: types.Message):

## some code

async def periodic():

    while True:
##    some code
        await asyncio.sleep(60)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger.info("Starting script")
    executor.start_polling(dp, on_startup=on_start, on_shutdown=on_stop)
```

Пытаюсь переписать код на aiogram3, Executor оттуда убрали, и что бы я не пробовал, выход по Ctrl/C вызывает ошибку.  Подскажите, как этот функционал можно воспроизвести на Aiogram3?